# Is there a modern iteration of Einstein's Brownian motion theory?

Tags: brownian-motion

I was arguing with my friend that Brownian motion, in the sense of a pollen moving in the fluid, could be explained by physics laws (such as $F=ma$) and statistics laws.

To check it out I found Albert Einstein's paper, "Investigations on the theory of Brownian motion", however I found it a bit hard to understand. It starts with osmotic pressure which i have no idea, and the paper is 114 pages long, though in big font.

I'm wondering if there's an easier iteration? hopefully shorter?

Comment: Cross-posted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/129510/2451